# How to parse nested arrays in a model in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse some json data from our backend server.
To start of, here's the data it returns:

```
{
  "newsitem": {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Some title",
    "images": [
        "IMG_0147.JPG",
        "desert1.jpg"
    ],
    "videos": [
        "AEOpX8tmiUI",
        "kxopViU98Xo"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to parse this in my model:

```
App.Newsitem = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),

    images: DS.attr('array'),
    videos: DS.attr('array')
});
```

But this give me an error that 'array' is not supported. How should I go with parsing this data and how should I print out the values of `images` and  `videos` in the DOM through a handlebars template? I'm looking for a best-practise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of credits to `nerdyworm` on the `#emberjs` channel for the answer: you have to create your own serialize/deserialize methods for your new data type like this:

```
DS.JSONTransforms.array = {
  serialize: function(jsonData) {
    return Ember.typeOf(jsonData) == 'array' ? jsonData : [];
  },
  deserialize: function(externalData) {
    return Ember.typeOf(externalData) == 'array' ? externalData : [];
  }
}
```

Then in your handlebars template you can do:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="newsitem">
    <div class="detail">
        {{#each image in images}}
            {{image}}<br/>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how I can bind `{{image}}` to `<img src="" />`, so if someone has a suggestion: shoot!